# When is checking local min along every line restriction sufficienct to determine local min?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

For a convex function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$, where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, if $X^{*}$ is a local min, (hence global min), we can check along every line restriction to verify $X^{*}$ is indeed the local min. However, oftentimes in optimization, the function is not convex, or no longer convex after a change of variable. Therefore this [does not always work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855859/does-having-a-minimum-along-all-lines-imply-that-the-function-has-a-minimum/855874)

> So I wonder in general, for $C^{2}$ function,  $f:S \to \mathbb{R}, S \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, does there exist a necessary sufficient, or very weak sufficient condition to guarantee that if $X^{*}$ is the local min along every line restriction, it is actually a local min?

Of course, checking for gradient and hessian works in the interior, but this is not possible on the boundary. Also, what about the case if we lift the $C^{2}$ restriction?

---

Edit: I have changed this question from the original version so it can be more focused on my question.

Comment: If there was a point of lower value, then the directional derivative in the direction of that point would be strictly negative. This is where convexity comes in.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. What about in general though? Does there exist some condition that can be imposed on the function such that checking every directional derivative would be sufficient?

Comment: Slight hyperbole here, but to some extent, the beauty of convex programming is that $x^*$ solves $\min_{x \in C} f(x)$ **iff** $\operatorname{df}(x^*,x-x^*) \ge 0$ for all $x \in C$. $C$ is a closed convex set, $f$ convex, Gateaux differentiable.