# local minimum is isolated

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$.

Claim: For all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ the function $\varphi(t)=f(at,bt)=b^2t^2-3a^2bt^3+2a^4t^4$ has an isolated local minimum at $t=0$.

I proved that $\varphi$ has an local minimum at $t=0$ (because $\varphi'(0)=0$ and $\varphi''(0)>0$) but I don't know why this is an isolated minimum. Isolated means that there is a $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $t\neq 0$ with  $|t|<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $\varphi(0)<\varphi(t)$. But how to define $\epsilon$?

Can you help me?

Edit: If for example $b=0$ (see the hint below), then $\varphi(t)=2a^4t^4$ has a local minimum in $t=0$ too. But what does that have to do with "isolated"?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73949/why-is-0-0-not-a-minimum-of-fx-y-y-3x2y-x2

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You know the minimum *value*, and so can check explicitly where the minimum is achieved. Write
$$
f(at, bt) = t^{2}(b^{2} - 3a^{2}bt + 2a^{4}t^{2}),
$$
and separate the cases (i) $b \neq 0$ and (ii) $b = 0$ and $a \neq 0$.

Comment: okay. For example if $b=0$, then $\varphi(t)=f(at,0)=2a^4t^4$ has a local minimum in $t=0$ too. But what does this say about "isolated"?

Comment: The issue to address is: For fixed $(a, b) \neq (0, 0)$, where (other than $t = 0$) does the function $\varphi(t) = f(at, bt)$ achieve the value $0$? "Isolated" means that for each $(a, b)$, there is a $t$-interval about $0$ in which the only minimum of $\varphi$ is at $t = 0$. (In the extreme case $b = 0$, you can take this interval to be the entire line.)