# Show that on every line $ y=mx$ the function has a minimum at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus

This question is from Apostol's calculus $2$:

Let $f(x,y)=3x^4 - 4x^2y+y^2$ . Show that on everyline $y=mx$ the function has a minimun at the origin.

Here's my solution attempt:

I've composed this function with the curve $\gamma(x)=(x,mx)$ getting:

$f(x,mx)=3x^4-4mx^3+m^2x^2$. Differentiating, we get that $f'(x,mx)=0$ iff $x=0$.

So, $x=0$ is a critical point of our function. Differentiating one more time, we have:

$f''(x,mx)=36x^2-24xm+2m^2$. Evaluating at the point $x=0$, it follows that $f''\ge0$ , since $m^2\ge0$, and hence we have a minimal point.

Is it correct? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds very good, the work makes sense. But, why not show $ƒ'' \geq 0$ for all m? It's a simple quadratic, wouldn't be hard to show.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73949/why-is-0-0-not-a-minimum-of-fx-y-y-3x2y-x2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor points:

Don't write $f'(x,mx)$ when $f$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$. Introduce the pullback $g(x):=f(x,mx)$.

The function $g$ has derivative $g'(x)=12x^3-12mx^2+2m^2x$. This vanishes in $3$ points when $m\ne0$, hence you should replace the "iff" by "if".

You found $g''(0)=2m^2$. This is $>0$ when $m\ne0$, hence $g$ has a strict local minimum at $x=0$ in this case.

Now the only serious complaint: We don't know yet what happens in the case $m=0$; therefore we have to check this case separately: When $m=0$ we get $g(x)=x^4$ which has a strict local minimum at $x=0$ as well.

By the way: There is also an "instant solution" of this problem: Observe that
$$f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-3x^2)\ ,$$
and draw a figure showing the parabolas $y-x^2$ and $y=3x^2$. Now think about the sign of $f(x,y)$ in the four regions so created, and draw a few lines through the origin.