# Show that $\ f(x,y)$ has a saddle point at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Show that $\ f(x,y)=(y-x^3)(y-8x^3)$ has a saddle point at the origin

What I did:

I calculated the first partial derivatives and found that (0,0) is a critical point

$\ f_x=48x^5-27x^2y$ and$\ f_y=-9x^3+2y$

$\ f_x=f_y=0$ if $\ x=0$ and$\ y=0$

Next, I tried to apply the second partial derivative test

$\ f_{xx}=240x^4-54xy$ and$\ f_{xx}(0,0)=0$

$\ f_{xy}=-27x^2$ and$\ f_{xy}(0,0)=0$

$\ f_{yy}=2$ and$\ f_{yy}(0,0)=2$

So $\ f_{xx}(0,0) f_{yy}(0,0)-(f_{xy}(0,0))^2=0$

The second derivative test is inconclusive, what can I do?

The problem also wants me to show that $\ f$ has a minimum over every line that goes through the origin (y=mx), but I haven't tried to do it since I'm stuck at the first part.

Help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $(0, 0)$ not a minimum of $f(x, y) = (y-3x^2)(y-x^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73949/why-is-0-0-not-a-minimum-of-fx-y-y-3x2y-x2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ f(x,y)=(y-x^3)(y-8x^3)$ now consider these two curves $$g(y)=f(0,y)=y^2 $$ and $$h(x)=f(x,2x^3)= -6x^6$$

Traveling on the curve $g$ you fall down to a minimum point at origin, but by
traveling On the curve $h$ you rise up to a maximum point at origin. This shows origin is indeed a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would try to find points greater and lesser than $f(0,0)=0$ as close as you want of $(0,0)$.

To find this, you can take $f(0,y)=y^2$ and on the line $x=0$, we easily see that all points near $(0,0)$ are greater than $0$.

Finding a point under $0$ is somewhat tricky-er. To do this, we want $y-x^3$ to be positive, while $y-8x^3$ to be negative (we could also do this the other way around). Look at the sequence of points $f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n^3})=\left(\frac{2}{n^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n^3}-\frac{8}{n^3}\right)=\frac{-6}{n^6}<0$.